# What is the difference between "java dynamic web project" and "Gradle project"

Tags: java, gradle

I am a beginner in learning Java. kindly give a detailed explain or add a video link of the same.

Answer (score 3):

### **Dynamic web projects**

Dynamic web projects can contain dynamic Java EE resources such as servlets, JSP files, filters, and associated metadata, in addition to static resources such as images and HTML files.

Java EE conventions may represent extra overhead if you only want to create a static, content-based Web application, which contains no dynamic files, such as JSP files or servlets. In this case, when you need only the most basic Web project, you might want to use the static Web project type (see Static Web projects). Note that static Web projects can be converted to dynamic Web projects by selecting Convert to a Dynamic Web Project, from the Project menu.

Dynamic Web projects are mostly embedded in Enterprise Application projects. The wizard that you use to create a dynamic Web project will also create an Enterprise Application (EAR) project if it does not already exist. The wizard will also update the application.xml deployment descriptor of the specified Enterprise Application project to define the Web project as a module element. If you are importing a WAR file rather than creating a dynamic Web project new, the WAR Import wizard requires that you specify a Web project, which already requires an EAR project.

The Java EE model, and more specifically, the Sun Microsystems Java™ Servlet 2.3 Specification, defines a Web application directory structure that specifies the location of Web content files, class files, class paths, deployment descriptors, and supporting metadata. The Web project hierarchy mirrors that of the Web application created from a project. In the workbench, you can use the New Web Project wizard to create a new Web project.

The main project folder contains all development objects related to a Web application. The Web content folder contains the elements of the project necessary to create a Web application. This folder structure maps to the Web application archive (WAR) structure defined by Sun Microsystems.. The following default elements are located in the Web project folder hierarchy:

**Web Deployment Descriptor**

The standard Web application deployment descriptor (the web.xml file).

**JavaSource**
Contains the project's Java source code for classes, beans, and servlets. When these resources are added to a Web project, they are automatically compiled and the generated files are added to the WEB-INF/classes directory. The contents of the source directory are not packaged in WAR files unless an option is specified when a WAR file is created.

**imported_classes folder**
This folder may be created during a WAR import, and contains class files that do not have accompanying source. The imported_classes folder is a Java classes folder; Java classes folders can also be created using the Web project Java Build Path properties page.

**WebContent folder**
The mandatory location of all Web resources, including HTML, JSP, graphic files, and so on. If the files are not placed in this directory (or in a subdirectory structure under this directory), the files will not be available when the application is executed on a server. The Web content folder represents the contents of the WAR file that will be deployed to the server. Any files not under the Web content folder are considered development-time resources (for example, .java files, .sql files, and .mif files), and are not deployed when the project is unit tested or published.

**META-INF**
This directory contains the MANIFEST.MF file, which is used to map class paths for dependent JAR files that exist in other projects in the same Enterprise Application project. An entry in this file will update the run-time project class path and Java build settings to include the referenced JAR files.

**theme**
The suggested directory for cascading style sheets and other style-related objects.

**WEB-INF**

Based on the Sun Microsystems Java Servlet 2.3 Specification, this directory contains the supporting Web resources for a Web application, including the web.xml file and the classes and lib directories.

**/classes**
This directory is for servlets, utility classes, and the Java compiler output directory. The classes in this directory are used by the application class loader to load the classes.
Folders in this directory will map package and class names, as in: /WEB-INF/classes/com/mycorp/servlets/MyServlet.class.
Do not place any .class files directly into this directory. The .class files are placed in this directory automatically when the Java compiler compiles Java source files that are in the Java Resources directory. Any files placed directly in this directory will be deleted by the Java compiler when it runs.

**/lib**
The supporting JAR files that your Web application references. Any classes in .jar files placed in this directory will be available for your Web application

**Libraries**
The supporting JAR files that your Web application references. This folder mirrors the content of the lib folder. In addition, Web Library Projects, which are "virtual" JAR files that do not physically reside in the Web project, but are associated with Java projects elsewhere in your workspace, are included in this folder. They are packaged with your project when you export the application's WAR file.
Note: A library entry on the Java build path will remain there unless the actual JAR file is deleted from the WEB-INF/lib folder. If you remove a library path entry but not the JAR file, the library entry will be re-added to the path automatically.

---

### **Gradle Projects :**

**Gradle** is a general purpose build management system. Gradle projects can be something which should be built or something that should be done.

Each project consists of tasks. A task represents a piece of work which a build performs, e.g., compile the source code or generate the Javadoc.

These build files are based on a Domain Specific Language (DSL). In this file you can use a combination of declarative and imperative statements. You can also write Groovy or Kotlin code, whenever you need it. Tasks can also be created and extended dynamically at runtime.

The following listing represents a very simple build file.

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello Gradle'
    }
}
```

To execute the hello task in this build file, type gradle hello on the command line in the directory of the build file. If the Gradle output should be suppressed, use the -q (quiet) parameter.

```
gradle hello

# alternative add the -q flag
gradle -q hello
```

Whats we get extra with gradle is -

**Declarative builds and convention over configuration**
Gradle uses a Domain Specific Language (DSL) based on Groovy to declare builds. The DSL provides a flexible language that can be extended by us. As the DSL is based on Groovy, we can write Groovy code to describe a build and use the power and expressiveness of the Groovy language.

Gradle is designed to be a build language and not a rigid framework. The Gradle core itself is written in Java and Groovy. To extend Gradle, we can use Java and Groovy to write our custom code. We can even write our custom code in Scala if we want to.

These projects have sensible convention-over-configuration settings that we probably already use ourselves. However, we have the flexibility to change these configuration settings if required for our projects.

**Gradle supports -**

**Ant Tasks and Maven repositories**

**Incremental builds**

With Gradle, we have incremental builds. This means the tasks in a build are only executed if necessary. For example, a task to compile source code will first check whether the sources have changed since the last execution of the task. If the sources have changed, the task is executed; but if the sources haven't changed, the execution of the task is skipped and the task is marked as being up to date.

**Multi-project builds**

Gradle has great support for multi-project builds. A project can simply be dependent on other projects or be a dependency of other projects. We can define a graph of dependencies among projects, and Gradle can resolve these dependencies for us. We have the flexibility to define our project layout as we want.

Gradle has support for partial builds. This means that Gradle will figure out whether a project, which our project depends on, needs to be rebuild or not. If the project needs rebuilding, Gradle will do this before building our own project.

**Gradle Wrapper**

The Gradle Wrapper allows us to execute Gradle builds even if Gradle is not installed on a computer. This is a great way to distribute source code and provide the build system with it so that the source code can be built.

Also in an enterprise environment, we can have a zero-administration way for client computers to build the software. We can use the wrapper to enforce a certain Gradle version to be used so that the whole team is using the same version. We can also update the Gradle version for the wrapper, and the whole team will use the newer version as the wrapper code is checked in to version control.

---

**Advantage of Gradle over IDE specific Dynamic web project**

**Project Modularization**

Project conventions suggest (or better, force) the developer to modularize the project. Instead of a monolithic project you are often forced to divide your project in smaller sub components, which make it easier debug and manage the overall project structure

**Dependency Management and Project Lifecycle**

Overall, with a good SCM configuration and an internal repository, the dependency management is quite easy, and you are again forced to think in terms of Project Lifecycle - component versions, release management and so on. A little more complex than the ant something, but again, an improvement in quality of the project.

**Portability**

Each IDE has its own project structure. While other IDEs may have the option to import Eclipse settings it may not be without problems.
Also Eclipse settings are very local. Importing an Eclipse project from another person will easily require reconfiguration (JDK path/version, etc).
In Gradle the local machine specifics are decoupled from projects, allowing people to share the same config file (pom.xml), regardless of which machine or IDE they use.
It’s easier to integrate with automatic integration tools. Headless compilation with Eclipse is rarely used and not super well documented.
Gradle handles and downloads dependencies automatically via ivy or maven plugins. It’s often problematic and painful, but Eclipse doesn’t do that at all. Manually downloading the libs, shared folders or USB shuffling is a hassle and dangerous.\

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic web projects can contain dynamic Java EE resources such as servlets, JSP files, filters, and associated metadata, in addition to static resources such as images and HTML files. Static web projects only contains static resources. When you create Web projects, you can include cascading style sheets and JSP tag libraries (for dynamic Web projects), so that you can begin development with a richer set of project resources.

Gradle uses a convention-over-configuration approach to building JVM-based projects that borrows several conventions from Apache Maven. In particular, it uses the same default directory structure for source files and resources, and it works with Maven-compatible repositories.

Comment: Is it that Dynamic web project, do not follow convention over configuration? are you sure? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6087/dgdeploy.html